# How do I make a simple email form submission in HTML?

Tags: html

I tried w3schools but it didn't help and I tried other websites too. I just wanna make a short html script that sends an email to an email address, but I keep reloading my email inbox and nothing comes up. Can you help?

```
<form action="MAILTO:MY_EMAIL@yahoo.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<input type="text" name="email" value="Email">
<input type="text" name="message" value="Message">

<input value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an 'HTML script'. The pseudo-protocol 'mailto:` is meant to be used with links to launch the user's default mail client. You cannot submit a form this way. W3Schools is not a highly regarded resource. Try Mozilla Developer Network: http://developer.mozilla.org/ Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a server side script here. HTML alone won't help you here. HTML is just the frontend logic. You need some script on backend that accepts this data you submit and actually sends out an email. To take the example in PHP, assuming u have the server set up and all or that your shared

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<input type="text" name="email" value="Email">
<input type="text" name="message" value="Message">

<input value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

### sendmail.php

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message=json_encode($_POST);
$receiver="MY_EMAIL@yahoo.com";
$mailer="mailer@myservice.com";

mail($email,"Message for enquiry or whatever",$message,  array("from"=>$mailer));
```

Answer (score 2):

There were, at some point, browsers that supported forms of this type. However, they're all gone now -- you will need a server-side script to send email. It's impossible to do using HTML alone.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing a few things.
When you Submit a form, it goes from the client (browser) to your server, which acts upon it. The form action needs to be a URL which handles the request. The mailto: URI scheme is not a valid action to use.

You have two choices:

You can create a mailto: link like this:
Send email

which will open your default email client,

OR

- You can put a URL corresponding to an end point on your server, something like

  form action="/send/mail"...

and have your server send the email

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to do this is using a service like [Zapier](https://zapier.com) or [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com). Both of them offer a way to create Zaps/Applets that can send an email when you post to a specific url.

This is what configuration would look like in IFTTT [image: IFTTT] and Zapier [image: Zapier].

IFTTT is simpler to setup, Zapier has more options, like sending to more than one emails. I believe IFTTT only lets you send to your account's email.